# Reversing elements of a vector between two indexes

Tags: c++, vector

I wanted to reverse the elements between two specific positions of a vector.Here is my code:

```
std::vector<int> shuffleState(std::vector<int> deck, int numberOfRiffleShuffles) {
if (numberOfRiffleShuffles%2 !=0)
std::reverse(deck.begin()+1, deck.end()-1);
return deck;
}
```

The compiler says:

```
undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with the code and what i can do to fix this "issue".

Comment: Do not guess! Read the documentation. Your loop - that's nonsense right there.

Comment: You fixed the code based on a posted answer. Don't do that, it makes the answer(s) irrelevant. You then changed the problem to a different error message. Don't do that either, post a new question for a different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `size()` (# of stored items) rather than `capacity()` (allocated storage capacity).

If you want to reverse order of a range, you don't need a loop, just one command.

Answer (score 8):

You should pass to `std::reverse` a couple of *bidirectional iterators*:

```
std::reverse( d.begin() + 1, d.end() - 1 );
```

This will reverse all the `vector` but the first and the last elements.